# SilverLight refresh label in cycle

Tags: silverlight

I have simple problem. I want to refresh label in Silverlight in for cycle after I press silverlight button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            label1.Content = i;
            label1.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

So I want to see in my label refresh... every second new number 1 , 2, 3 ..... until 99.
But When I press button I only see after 99 seconds number 99. Hmm....How to create something like this in silvelight that the label will refresh after each number.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

With `Thread.Sleep(1000)` you block your UI thread so you can't see anything. You need [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). See MSDN sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189084%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Hello. Thank you but the problem is same if I delete this row. The problem is that SilverLight is unable to refresh on client this label. Only after the method ends label refresh. So the problem is that I don't know how to refresh the label before the methond ends. Thank You

Comment: Look at the sample I gave you. Did you try it?